# How to check for a logged in admin in polymerfire?

Tags: firebase, polymerfire, firebase-polymer

I just changed from a json datastore for my single app Polymer web app to polymerfire. All data in my web app is public, and only one admin should change data, so I have just one top node for all page data.

For login, I use the firebase-auth element with a public provider, and have set the rules to give my admin write privileges.

But now I am struggling around how to give the logged in admin a feedback to show he is logged in. For that, I have added a second top node in my database ('isAdmin'), that is only readible for a logged in admin, with a key of 'Admin' and a Boolean value of 'true'. I have tried to bind to that with firebase-document and use it in a dom-if template like so:

```
    <firebase-auth 
        id="auth" 
        user="{{user}}"
        provider="google"
        app-name="myApp"
        signed-in="{{signedIn}}">
    </firebase-auth>        
    <firebase-document
        log
        id="adminCheck"
        app-name="myApp"
        path="/isAdmin"
        data="{{firebaseAdmin}}">
    </firebase-document>

    <paper-button raised on-tap="login" hidden="[[user]]">Log in</paper-button>        
    <paper-button raised on-tap="logout" hidden="[[!user]]">Log out</paper-button>

    <template is="dom-if" if="[[firebaseAdmin.Admin]]" restamp>
        <span>Hello [[user.displayName]]!</span>
    </template>
```

However, as only a logged in admin can read the node, the admin value actually never changes in my javascript, only if I refresh the browser after login. So if I try to log the state like so:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-login',
        properties: {
            user: {
                type: Object
            },
            firebaseAdmin: {
                type: Object
            },
        },
        _checkAdmin: function() {
            var myVal = this.$.adminCheck.getStoredValue('/isAdmin');
            console.log('Value for admin stored in firebase-document element: ' + myVal.Admin);
            console.log('Polymer property for admin: ' + this.firebaseAdmin.Admin);

        },
        login: function() {
            this.$.auth.signInWithPopup();
            this._checkAdmin();
        },
        logout: function() {            
            this.$.auth.signOut();
            this._checkAdmin();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I'd always get:

`Value for admin stored in firebase-document element: undefined
Polymer property for admin: undefined`

back from my _checkAdmin function, even if logged in. Only when I refresh the page after admin login, I'd get a log from firebase-document with the stored object at the isAdmin node:

```
Got stored value! Object {Admin: true}
```

, and now I'd be stuck with this value, even if logged out. My _checkAdmin function would then always log this:

```
Value for admin stored in firebase-document element: undefined
Polymer property for admin: true
```

I then tried to various things unsuccessfully, but now I guess this is not the appropriate way to check for a logged in admin? I just don't think I should check uid's in javascript directly.

Glad if any pro would be around and wanting to help me out, Alex

Thanks to Michael Bleigh's help I finally got it working, like so:

```
<dom-module id="my-login">
<template>
    <style>
        span {
            margin-left: 1rem;
        }
        paper-button {
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #333 66%);
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
             background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }
    </style>        
    <firebase-auth 
        id="auth" 
        user="{{user}}"
        provider="google"
        app-name="myApp"
        signed-in="{{signedIn}}">
    </firebase-auth>        
    <firebase-document
        app-name="myApp"
        path="/admins/[[user.uid]]"
        data="{{isAdmin}}">
    </firebase-document>

    <paper-button raised on-tap="login" hidden="[[user]]">Log in</paper-button>        
    <paper-button raised on-tap="logout" hidden="[[!user]]">Log out</paper-button>        
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[admin]]" restamp>
        <span hidden="[[!user]]">Hello [[user.displayName]]!</span>
    </template>


</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-login',
        properties: {
            user: {
                type: Object
            },
            isAdmin: {
                type: Object
            },
            admin: {
                type: Boolean,
                computed: '_checkAdmin(isAdmin)'
            }
        },            
        _checkAdmin: function(isAdmin) {
            if (typeof isAdmin === 'boolean') {
                console.log('Polymer property for admin is defined');
                return true;
            }
        },
        login: function() {
            this.$.auth.signInWithPopup();

        },
        logout: function() {            
            this.$.auth.signOut();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical way to solve this is by writing admins as a boolean map in the Realtime Database:

```
- admins
  - {uid}: true
  - {uid}: true
```

You would then set up security rules like:

```
{
  "admins": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
    }
  }
}
```

This allows each user to read their own `admins` node to check whether or not they're an admin. Now, finally, you would bind to that location:

```
<firebase-auth user="{{user}}"></firebase-auth>
<firebase-document path="/admins/[[user.uid]]" data="{{isAdmin}}"></firebase-document>
```

The `data` will be `null` for non-admins and `true` for admins when signed in. Another note is that you **must not rely on UI switching alone for admin control**. You should write your security rules such that only a user with a uid in the `admins` node can write to admin-protected areas of your database.

Comment: This works perfect, thank you so much! I guess I went wrong because I thought I didn't need a dynamic uid path, as I only have one admin.